# Plone training setup error for Products.GenericSetup

Tags: plone, genericsetup

I'm trying to learn how to develop an addon for Plone 5.
in order to do that I am sticking to the Plone 5 training (https://training.plone.org).

I am installing a Vagrant/Virtualbox machine with plone on it as suggested by the training, but when i try to run buildout I always  get this error

```
vagrant@training:/vagrant/plonetheme.tango$ ./bin/buildout
Develop: '/vagrant/plonetheme.tango/.'
Updating _mr.developer.
Installing instance.
/home/vagrant/buildout-cache/eggs/setuptools-20.7.0-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py:187: RuntimeWarning: You have iterated over the result of pkg_resources.parse_version. This is a legacy behavior which is inconsistent with the new version class introduced in setuptools 8.0. In most cases, conversion to a tuple is unnecessary. For comparison of versions, sort the Version instances directly. If you have another use case requiring the tuple, please file a bug with the setuptools project describing that need.
  stacklevel=1,
Version and requirements information containing products.genericsetup:
  [versions] constraint on products.genericsetup: 1.8.0
  Requirement of plonetheme.tango[test]: Products.GenericSetup>=1.8.2
  Requirement of plone.app.testing: Products.GenericSetup
While:
  Installing instance.
Error: The requirement ('Products.GenericSetup>=1.8.2') is not allowed by your [versions] constraint (1.8.0)`
```

I tried to update Products.GenericSetup via easy_install but buildout seems to ignore the newer version in the python folder.

Comment: There also is a issue tracker for the training if you encounter further issues: https://github.com/collective/training_buildout/issues

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Somewhere in your buildout definition (I don't know how Vagrant install it so you must look around inside .cfg files) you probably have:

```
[versions]
...
Products.Genericsetup=1.8.0
```

...while the theme requires version 1.8.2.

Just add this:

```
[versions]
...
Products.Genericsetup=1.8.2
```

Comment: I added the recommended line to the buildout.cfg file in the [versions] section and it worked. Thank you!